# HTMLto texture on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, browser, opengl-es, uiwebview

Is there a way to grab the pixels from an UIWebView and render it to an opengl texture?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what it takes to load an opengl texture.  But this will convert the data from a view into a jpeg.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

sorry for the half answer. hope someone can take it from here...